# how to hide a success message after some time in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento1.9.3, global-messages, success-message

how can I hide messages after certain time. I'm using a custom model.

```
$redirectMsg = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess('hii');
```

Comment: You do it with `js`

Comment: how please! i found this functions but where should i past it.  setTimeout(function () {
                        $redirectMsg(self.selector).find('.message').removeClass('show');
                        self.isHidden('false');
                    }, 5000);

Comment: Hide all messages in all pages ?

Comment: yes but where should i write this code I m beginner in magento

Answer (score 0):

To add your `js` code in all pages, let's do it as well as it should.

First, you have to create a new js file, then you declare this `js` file because Magento doesn't know it yet.

1. Declare `js`:

> ```
>     app/design/frontend/{your_package_theme}/{your_theme_name}/layout/local.xml
> ```

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <default>
            <reference name="head">
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/glob-messages.js</name></action>
            </reference>
        </default>
    </layout>
```

2. Create `glob-messages.js` file :

> ```
>     skin/frontend/{your_package_theme}/{your_theme_name}/js/glob-messages.js
> ```

```
    /*Your js code goes here...*/
```

<sup>**Flush cache, then your code is in place.**</sup>